# Labeling all rows in a dataframe with consecutive serial numbers placed in an additional column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying add an additional column in a dataframe with serial numbers. I do not know how to do this without using a FOR loop, which is taking too long.

Example:

This is what I have:

```
COL1 COL2 
  A   X
  B   X
  A   Y 
  B   Z
```

Notice that all rows are unique.

This is what I want:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
  A   X    0
  B   X    1
  A   Y    2
  B   Z    3
```

Comment: Do you mean `df['COL3'] = df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2']).ngroup()` or `df['COL3'] = np.arange(len(df))` or maybe just `df['COL3'] = df.index` if the DataFrame has a default index?

Comment: Tx, latter seemed to work in a jiffy. FOR loops seem a terrible idea w/ PANDAS.